How to generate separate patch files for all unstaged Git files?
To create a git diff for unstaged files compared to HEAD, I'm using the following command, as suggested here:
git diff -p HEAD

Now, I want to write patches for each file independently as separate patch files. The options in git diff --help only show how to redirect the output of git diff -p HEAD to a single file, rather than to the sysout.
Is there a way to generate separate patch files for all unstaged files?

My guess is that you can do git patch -p HEAD -- some-file > some-patch-file.patch... for each file. You could write a bash 1-liner to produce all separate patch files in a single shot.

Is there a way to get al unstaged files of a certain extension in the directory?

sounds like you want to create a custom git command. https://gitbetter.substack.com/p/automate-repetitive-tasks-with-custom

This sounds good, I can give that a shot

@tandem List unstaged files: git diff --name-only; list staged files: git diff --cached --name-only; list both staged and unstaged files: git diff --name-only HEAD. List only files with extension: git diff --name-only -- "*.py"; quotes are required to avoid the shell to expand *; with quotes *.py is passed to Git and interpreted by Git in the entire working tree, not by the shell in the current directory.
